# convolution neural network getting an value error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multiclass-classification

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
# Note the input shape is the desired size of the training dataset 8000 * 10
# This is the first convolution
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape= (8000, 10, 4)),  
# Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
# 512 neuron hidden layer
tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'), 
])

model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=25, validation_data = X_cv, verbose = 1)
```

---

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-166-5defea4eaeb5> in <module>
  3 model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics= 
 ['accuracy'])
  4 
5 history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=25, validation_data = X_cv, verbose = 1)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in 
fit(self,0 x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, 
shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, 
validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
707         steps=steps_per_epoch,
708         validation_split=validation_split,
709         shuffle=shuffle)
710 
711     # Prepare validation data.

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in 
_standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, 
steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
2649           feed_input_shapes,
2650           check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
2651           exception_prefix='input')
2652 
2653     if y is not None:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in 
standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
374                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
375                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
376                            'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
377         if not check_batch_axis:
378           data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_50_input to have 4 dimensions, but 
got array with shape (8000, 10)
```

---

context: I am using this convolution neural network for multiclass classification(4- 
   classes), providing the input shape as of my X_train dataset(8000, 10). But getting an error 
   as shown above . I am not getting why it is expected 4 dimensions. Or what can be the 
   solution. Plz help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your input? is it an image? Conv2D layers expect  images as input, that is why it should be 4D: (samples, width, height, channels)

Comment: No my input is not an image. But i guess Conv2D works for texts as well.

Comment: Even i remove the conv. layer and use :                  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, input_shape=(8000, 10)),                                                                                                  I get the similar error.   ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_66_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8000, 10).